# Max subtree sum in tree with limited length

Tags: graph-algorithm

I've got a tree structure.
The task is to find the biggest sum/weight of path nodes, but i can only move **n times**. Thats ok, but going "up"/"back" cost nothing.
How can i accomplish that?

Below is my code, but the problem is that the each node can only be accessed once, so it doesnt work.

```
int mSum(Node* node, int mvLeft) {
    if (node == nullptr) { return 0; }
    if (mvLeft == 0) { return node->value; }
    mvLeft--;
    int sum = max(mSum(node->left, mvLeft), mSum(node->right, mvLeft));
    return node->value + max(sum, mSum(node->parent, mvLeft + 1));
}
```

Here is the example graph. The numbers on the nodes represent the cost of getting to it. Each node can be visited only once except going "back".
The **n step limit here is 3**, we're counting entering the graph too, so the proper result is 21 because: 2->8->11.
If we would have limit of 4 steps the result would be 31: 2->10->8->11
[image: Visualization of the example tree]
My friend tried to do it with DFS, is he right? What's the best algorithm?

Comment: you could try to add an array of visited notes to the paraemter list and count the node value only if its node is not in the array

Comment: of course i could, but then i would fall into removing -the-nodes-from-that-array problem, i think

Comment: memory is cheap these days, i would give every call its new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good answer is taking multiple routes at the same time.
I mean we could go with 2-length limit:

- 2 left 0 right
- 1 left 1 right
- 0 left 2 right

Working, but somewhat slow, code :)
Its working time is 28s while other solutions can go with 2s (10 not known tests)

```
int mSum(Node* node, int mvLeft) {
    mvLeft--;
    if (mvLeft < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (mvLeft == 0) {
        return node->value;
    }

    if (node->left != nullptr && node->right != nullptr) {
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= mvLeft; i++) {
            max = Max(max, mSum(node->left, i) + mSum(node->right, mvLeft - i));
        }
        return max + node->value;
    }
    else if (node->left != nullptr) {
        return mSum(node->left, mvLeft) + node->value;
    }
    else if (node->right != nullptr) {
        return mSum(node->right, mvLeft) + node->value;
    }
    return node->value;
}
```

Comment: Any faster ideas? Thats too slow